# Using NSUserDefaults in Xcode 5 to save the second opened view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I need to login from the first view controller by entering email and should navigate to the second view controller. The entered email in first view controller has to be displayed.

Until this, it is working fine. My problem is, even after I close the app completely, next time when I open app, it should show me the second view controller displaying the saved email. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Learn from here : https://youtu.be/GjlpBr5UcEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your login details in **NSUserDefaults** and after landing again check if email is already exit then show second controller and show same mail using  **NSUserDefaults**

On Login action save like this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Your email" forKey:@"emailId"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

On First controller Check on again Load

```
  NSString *emailStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"emailId"];
 if(emailStr.length != 0){
 //Send to next controller and show email Id
 }
```

Comment: @AnjanaKG : Please [accept it as answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question. :)

Comment: It goes to second view,even if we open app after uninstalling!!..It is not proper.Would be better if we write code to retrieve in the - **(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions**???